# Convert multiple file upload to several single file uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input

I need to convert a html `<input type="file" multiple>` to several `<input type="file">` after the user selects multiple files, and break their selection down so each file upload contains one of their files. This should be done with javascript/jQuery. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin to do this.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

this page has a setup demo
[setup](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup)